# $\frac{dx^5}{dx^2},$ the derivative of $x^5$ with respect to $x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

> Let $f(x)=x^5.$ Find its derivative with respect to $x^2$ , i.e., find $\frac{dx^5}{dx^2}.$

We know that $\frac{dx^5}{dx}=5x^4.$

But what should I do when it is needed to take derivative with respect to $x^2 ,x^3$ or other weird things different from classical derivatives?

**My approaches:**

**$1-)$** Say $x^2=a$ , then $x^5 =a^{5/2}$. Hence , find $$\frac{da^{5/2}}{da}=\frac{5}{2}a^{3/2}=\frac{5}{2}x^{3}$$

**$2-)$** Find $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x^2+h)-f(x^2)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x^2+h)^5-(x^2)^5}{h}=5x^8$$

My approaches conflict. Why do they give different results?

**Addendum:** Extra examples will be appreciated, for example, $dx^7 /dx^3,\;dx^6/dx^5.$

Comment: In general, you can find the derivative of a function $f$ with respect to another function $g$ using the chain rule:
$$\frac{\mathrm d f}{\mathrm d x} = \frac{\mathrm d f}{\mathrm d g} \frac{\mathrm d g}{\mathrm d x}.$$

Comment: $\frac{d(x^5)}{dx}=5x^4$, $\frac{d(x^2)}{dx}=2x$, then $\frac{d(x^5)}{d(x^2)}=\frac{5x^4 dx}{2x dx}=\frac{5}{2}x^3$. Your second approach gives derivative of $t^5$ with respect to $t$, taken at $t=x^2$. This quantity is not what you need to find.

Comment: Ugh: another resolved Question that can never have an Accepted Answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how a Physicist would do it
$$\frac{dx^5}{dx^2}\frac{dx^2}{dx}=\frac{dx^5}{dx}=5x^4$$
Since $\frac{dx^2}{dx}=2x$, we get
$$\frac{dx^5}{dx^2}=\frac{5x^3}{2}$$

Comment: this is nice :) btw , do you see the error in my second approach ?

Comment: The error in your second approach is that there is no justification to use the limit on the left hand side.

Comment: what do you mean by "there is no justification to use the limit on the left hand side." . I think , i can handle the issue using the definition of derivative. Can you be clearer ?

Comment: @jason-192856 See parth’s answer

Answer (score 6):

In you 2nd attempt is wrong as stated

What is $\frac{dx^5}{dx^2}$

It is ratio of change in $ x^5$ to change in $x^2$

So $$\frac{dx^5}{dx^2}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^5-x^5}{(x+h)^2-x^2}
=\frac{5x^4h}{2xh}=\frac{5}{2}x^3$$

For general $\frac{dx^n}{dx^m}$

$$\frac{dx^m}{dx^n}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^m-x^m}{(x+h)^n-x^n}
=\frac{mx^{m-1}h}{nx^{n-1}h}=\frac{m}{n}x^{m-n}$$

And for your second approach $x^5$ is not a function of $x^2$

Comment: Got it ? @jason-192856

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt can't be right: it contains $f(x^2)$, which surely has no influence on the value of $\frac{df(x)}{d(x^2)}$. You have to go back to what the expression
$$\frac{df(x)}{dg(x)}$$
means. It is (roughly speaking) the amount by which $f(x)$ changes divided by the amount by which $g(x)$ changes. If $x$ changes by $h$, then $f(x)$ changes by (roughly) $hf'(x)$, and $g(x)$ changes by (roughly) $hg'(x)$. So in the limit, the expression is equal to
$$\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
which in your case is $\frac{5x^4}{2x}=\frac52x^3$. Your extra examples are easy to evaluate using this approach.

Comment: why did you need to rewrite my first approach ?

Comment: @jason-192856: Sorry! I should have read to the end. I've written a new answer.

Answer (score -1):

In your second approach you should substitute as follows:

(note:in my solution $f(x) \neq x^5$)

$\frac{dx^5}{dx^2}=\frac{d((x^2)^{\frac{5}{2}})}{dx^2}$

So $f(x^2)=(x^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}$ which implies $f(x)=x^{\frac{5}{2}} $

\begin{align*} \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x^2+h)-f(x^2)}{h}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x^2+h)^{\frac{5}{2}}-(x^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}{h}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x^2+h)^{\frac{5}{2}}-(x^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}{h} \cdot\frac{(x^2+h)^{\frac{5}{2}}+(x^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}{(x^2+h)^{\frac{5}{2}}+(x^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{(x^2+h)^{\frac{5}{2}}+(x^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x^2+h)^5-(x^2)^5}{h}\\&=\frac{1}{2x^5}\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x^2+h)^5-(x^2)^5}{h}\\&=\frac{1}{2x^5}\cdot5x^8\\&=\frac{5}{2}x^3
\end{align*}

Comment: "$f(x^2)=(x^2)^{\frac52}$": No, $f(x^2)=(x^2)^5=x^{10}$. That is elementary.

Comment: @TonyK I take $f(x^2)=(x^2)^\frac{5}{2}$ from  $\frac{dx^5}{dx^2}=\frac{d((x^2)^{\frac{5}{2}})}{dx^2}$

Comment: @TonyK I don't consider $f(x)=x^5$

Comment: $f(x^2)=x^{10}$ if I consider $f(x)=x^5$

Comment: concentrate well on steps of my solution